# Moodle connnection error after update [Error: Database connection failed]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, moodle

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 (beta) while I have been using Moodle since some months. In last one week I updated my system/software couple of times and then out of nowhere, now, when I go to `http://localhost/moodle/` I get a white screen with following text

```
Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php
```

When I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` and provide credentials, I get an error message:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

I don't want to reinstall this as I would lose a lot of data.